# array in vue template is not updating

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I am creating a dynamic array in my vue. This array is getting populated in script from a JSON array, but not updating in template. In template it is returning blank array. Here is my code:

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{users}} <!-- this is returning blank --> 
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data(){
      return {
        users: []
      }
    },
    created(){
      this.fetchUsers();
    },
    methods:{
      fetchUsers(){
        fetch('api/single')
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(res => {
            this.users= res.data;
              console.log(this.users); //this is showing the data 
      })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
   }
 }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens when the data property value is not initialised in the correct way. Instead of assigning your array from the fetch request to your data property you should use **[vm.$set](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-set)** method provided by Vue api. Thanks to this reactivity will be preserved. In the matter of fact you can even remove the users array declaration from your data object since vm.$set will override it.

So your method will look like this:

```
fetchUsers(){
        fetch('api/single')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => {
            this.$set(this, 'users', res.data) // target, key, value
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.$nextTick( () => {
  this.fetchUsers();
})
```

You can try `this.$nextTick()`. Because, the update of the DOM is asynchronous in Vue.

Comment: fetchUsers() method is working fine actually. the problem is anything populated in fatch() is not getting updated outside fetch(). even not inside fetchUsers() method

Answer (score 0):

Fetch API send asynchronous request, so users is displayed before data are loaded from API. Call computed method binded to users.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem has to do with reactivity with arrays. Try using a foreach loop to populate your data or as suggested use vm.$set

```
res.data.forEach(element => {
  this.users.push(element);
});
```

For more information about arrays reactivity please take a look at [vuejs common gotchas](https://vuejs.org/2016/02/06/common-gotchas/#Why-isn%E2%80%99t-the-DOM-updating)